# drag to destroy an element in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to simulate some sort of drag and drop to delete capability on my site (like the recycle bin/trash on windows/osx)

I have a bunch of objects in the database that are being represented by ruby as `div` on my site. 
I know I can add a drag capability to each of the divs using jquery, but I am not sure what to do afterward.

How do I assigned a specific area (an image) to initiate the destroy command? Since each object has a unique id the destroy should come from the object , but should be triggered by the trash image

Do I need to render my UI after such an action or would rails take care of it, like it does now with the regular destroy that comes in scaffolding ?

I know that it is a bit of an abstract question, but I am still in the design process and haven't written much code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention jquery, I'm guessing that you're using the `Draggable`s from jQuery UI.  You should also look at the docs for `Droppable`, which details how to handle drop events.  After you catch the drop event you could either do a full page post to your server, which would refresh the page and update the UI, or you could make an AJAX call and update the UI via JS.